# Binary to File download - But the downloaded file has no file extension?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void getFileAttachment(byte[] bytes)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = fileType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "test101");
    Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

> I'm trying to convert varbinary that is saved in SQL Server and I'm having trouble because the output file has no extension

Comment: Your `Content-Disposition` header has a filename without an extension - add one if you expect one to be there.

Comment: You're not adding an extension. Where do you expect it to come from?

Comment: Thank you, Its my fault I did not noticed that. Thanks Pal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "test101.filetype");
```

> My fault - I did not include the file extension in my database
>   Thanks for the comments!